# Using method.post without data

Tags: django

I'm using a timer as part of my app. The user can press a button to start or stop it, which update its DurationField in the database. From the user I only get the action of submitting, which triggers my view to produce the data that enters the database.

Question: is the post method required considering that the data entering the database is not a string or integer from the user, but generated from the view? Is there a better practice?

models.py

```
class Timer(models.Model):
    timer_start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    final_duration = models.DurationField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        timer_start_f = self.timer_start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        return f"Created: {timer_start_f}"

    def isActive(self):
        if self.final_duration is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def stop(self):
        if self.isActive():
            self.final_duration = timezone.now() - self.timer_start
            self.save()

    def time(self):
        if self.isActive():
            timedelta = timezone.now() - self.timer_start
            return f"{timedelta}".split(".")[0]
        else:
            return f"{self.final_duration}".split(".")[0]

    def timer_start_f(self):
        return self.timer_start.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %H:%M %p")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.indexView, name='index'),
    path('account/', views.timerView, name='timer')
]
```

views.py

```
def timerView(request):
    try:
        timer = Timer.objects.latest('timer_start')
    except Timer.DoesNotExist:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Timer.objects.create()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/")
        else:
            return render(request, 'pomodoro/timer.html', {'button_label': "Start Timer"})
    else:
        timer_list = Timer.objects.order_by('-timer_start')[1:]
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if timer.isActive():
                timer.stop()
            else:
                Timer.objects.create()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/")
        else:
            # "state" is used by javascript to run or stop the timer
            if timer.isActive():
                button_label = "Stop Timer"
                state = "active"
            else:
                button_label = "Start Timer"
                state = "not active"

            return render(request, 'pomodoro/timer.html', {'button_label': button_label, 'state': state, 'timer': timer, 'timer_list': timer_list})
```

Comment: you can use a simple form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django . You can have a non property form without problems.

Comment: Yes but in this case the question would be: "When you wrap your form in the template with a form tag, do you use a method POST or GET?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no one requiring you to wrap your views in POST. If you want someone to trigger your view with GET params (i.e. sharing a link with other user) then go with GET.

Otherwise I'd suggest wrapping whole view with `if POST` because it's meaning is closer to manipulating data in db than just selecting and showing data.

Comment: If I choose to use POST, do I still need the {% csrf_token %} in this situation ??

Comment: yes. You don't want to make this view [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#utilities)